# Apache Test Page: how do I get it to come up?

Tags: linux, apache, localhost, fedora

When I type the command, /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl start and go to http://localhost/, I get an "It Works!" Page. I installed Apache 2.4.25. I did not install Apache Tomcat. I'm trying to get the Apache test page to come up.
When I go to /usr/local/apache/htdocs and look at the index.html file using the vi editor, it shows that the localhost page is directed to the It Works! page.

To install Apache on my Fedora VM, I used the command ./configure --enable-mods-shared=all --prefix=/usr/local/apache --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre. Then I used the make clean command, followed by the make command, then followed by the make install command.

How do I get the Apache test page to come up INSTEAD of the It Works! page? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my httpd service was not running....
I figured this out by typing systemctl status httpd
I got the response that it was not running
So I typed systemctl start httpd
Then I put in the command /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl start
Then the test page came up!